# Gravitational acceleration at half Earth's radius

Tags: gravity, acceleration, earth

What would be the gravitational acceleration at half at Earth's radius? Something tells me it should be proportional to the mass distributed in that part, but I am not sure.

Of course, we assume we know what's the acceleration at Earth's surface. Also, for the sake of it let's assume Earth has uniform density and is a perfect sphere.

Comment: Your intuition tells you correctly. In a homogeneous ball the acceleration on the inside is a linear function of the distance from the center, because the mass inside r scales with r^3, which offsets the 1/r^2 dependence of gravity. Gravitational motion trough the center of the ball would therefor be harmonic (with the same period as a circular orbit around the entire mass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  For a sphere of uniform density, the acceleration drops off linearly.
$$g = g_{surface} \frac{r}{R}$$
where $r$ is the location under consideration, $R$ is the radius of the sphere and $r < R$.

Under such a scheme, gravity would be one half that at the surface.

The earth is not a uniform sphere though.  The outer crust is much less dense than the iron core.  Approaching this core then allows gravity to increase with depth for a distance before finally decreasing.

The [Gravity of Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) wiki page has a graph based on a reference model of the density of the earth with depth.

[image: Earth gravity with depth]

Under that model, gravity at half the earth's radius is just about equal to that at the surface.

Comment: Don't you mean $r/R$ where $R$ is the outer radius of the earth, and $r$ is the radius you are at?

Comment: Yes, my typing it is indeed messed up.  Edited.